# Can not deploy react js website by git hub

Tags: reactjs, github

I have just started react. My page works fine on localhost.
Now I am trying to host my page on github. I have used "npm run deploy" but it doesn't work. it appears 2 errors:

Error with Permissions-Policy header: Unrecognized feature: 'interest-cohort'.
[image]

You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
[image]
This is my package.json

```
{
  "homepage": "http://khanh0709.github.io/dolla",
  "name": "dolla",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.4",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^3.2.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these are not error. I have wait visual studio deploy it for 1 hour. And, it work